# Drop duplicate rows in a dataframe of particular column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
    Districtname    pincode
0   central delhi   110001
1   central delhi   110002
2   central delhi   110003
3   central delhi   110004
4   central delhi   110005
```

How can I drop rows based on column DistrictName and select the first unique value

The output I want:

```
    Districtname    pincode
0   central delhi   110001
```

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('Districtname')` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data Frames can be dropped using `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()` and defaults to keeping the first occurrence. In your case `DataFrame.drop_duplicates(subset = "Districtname")` should work. If you would like to update the same DataFrame `DataFrame.drop_duplicates(subset = "Districtname", inplace = True)` will do the job. Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `drop_duplicates` with `inplace=true`:

```
df.drop_duplicates('Districtname',inplace=True)
```